# Getting Data from Database Populated Checkbox Array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, checkbox

I recently created a View that included code to cycle through a database table and populate checkbox option titles based on data from the database.  This works perfectly.

For example:

```
   <?php foreach ($bud_items_si as $check_si => $label_text) : ?>

<?php $data_si = array(
            'name' => $check_si,
            'id' => $check_si,
            'value' => $check_si,
            'class' => '',                      
        );   

        echo '<div class="checkbox">';

        echo form_label(form_checkbox($data_si) . $label_text->bud_item, $check_si.'-label', array('for' => $check_si));

        echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to identify each individual checkbox for the validation file.  Typically to pass the checkbox values to the validation file it would look something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('sit_nm', 'Site Name', 'required');
```

Any ideas on how to get the individual checkbox name values from the array to pass to the validator?

Answer (score 0):

If all the check box are independent you should use a different name for each one!
If they are related you should try using an array `<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" />`